# Can you layer TableLayoutPanels?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to create a Windows Forms UI so it displays different controls depending on which button is pressed. I've grouped my controls in TableLayoutPanels and would like to stack them on top of each other so the form itself isn't larger than it needs to be. Once they're stacked a different TableLayoutPanel is displayed depending on which button is pressed.

The problem I have is that the TableLayoutPanels seem to be ignoring their z-order. I've got two on my form and I've sent one to the back and the other to the front, but the one I want in front won't show when I drag it over the other one. The one I sent to the back remains on the top.

This behaviour is happening within VS during design, and once each panel is complete I can stack them and it won't matter what order they're in, but it's annoying that I can't stack them while working in VS.

At the top of my form I have the following:

```
TableLayoutPanel activePanel;
```

I can then control which panel is visible with the following code:

```
activePanel.Visible = false;
activePanel = tlpCharacters;
activePanel.Visible = true;
```

I'd like to have them stacked while working in VS so my form isn't cluttered and layering these controls should be easy (works with a standard panel) so I'm wondering if it can't be done with the TableLayoutPanel control object?

Comment: Why don't you put the TableLayoutPanels on tabs? Or in a different form (not necessarily top-level)?

Comment: I don't like idea of stacking controls on top of each other. This makes it hard to edit in future, this is why there are many questions regarding `TabControl` without headers (to be able to switch between tabs). Rather put all those `TableLayoutPanel` into parent `FlowLayoutPanel`, making only one visible will display it in the most left-topmost corner.

Answer (score -1):

Sinatr had the perfect solution. I've switched to using TabControl and it's doing all the work for me. 
Thanks Sinatr. I wish I'd known about this control object when I started this project! That'll teach me to read the documentation.